# How to write Parsed and extracted data in XML before SqlServer Database insertion

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a set of Parser Component Functions in my web application which is capable of parsing and extracting data from following flat files

> 1) TabDelimitedFile.FileExtenstion are parsed and extracted using 
>   [This Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543789/How-to-parse-chunk-by-chunk-a-large-CSV-file-and-b)!!
>
> 2) File.XML files data are parsed and extracted using LinqToXml
>
> 3) Excel.xlsx files data are parsed and extracted using LinqtoExcel

Upon parsing and extraction of datasets i am inserting them to my Sql Server databAse using LinqToSql Classes and DBMLDataContext.

**My Requirement:** Before inserting the parsed and extracted data i would like to write those data sets in a XML file for user validation and then insert in the database tables upon user acceptance.

How to Proceed ?

My C# Parser Component Work Flow:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        try
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_data" + "/" + "Folder" + "/" + DropDownList1.Text + "/");
            IFileParser fileParser = new DefaultFileParser(First_Inserted);
            string destinationTableName = "My Table";
            string sourceFileFullName = GetFileFullName(path);
            IEnumerable<DataTable> dataTables = fileParser.GetFileData(sourceFileFullName);
            foreach (DataTable tbl in dataTables)
            {
                fileParser.WriteChunkData(tbl, destinationTableName, Map());
            }

            Appln_parse_xml1(path); 
            Appln_parse_xml2(path); 
            Appln_parse_xml3(path);
            Appln_parse_Excel(path);
        }
   }

private static bool Appln_parse_xml3(string _xml3_path)
    {
        bool parse_status = false;
        DataClasses1DataContext dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        //XML File

        List<string> xml3 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@_xml3_path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>();

        foreach (var _files in xml3)
        {

            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(_files);
            XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var groups = from g in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Group")
                         where (string)g.Attribute("name") == "Model Name"
                         select new First_DBML
                         {

                             Comp_Value = Decimal.Parse((from c in g.Elements(ns + "Group").Descendants(ns + "Cell")
                                                         where (string)c.Attribute("c") == "0"
                                                         select c.Value).First()),
                         };

            dbContext.First_DBMLs.InsertAllOnSubmit(groups);
            //Before Insertion need to write in xml for this Comp_value for user validation
            dbContext.SubmitChanges();
            // Inserting  into My_Table 
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, the requirement is little not clear. Do you want to save the data sets as physical xml files is it? How does the user accepts them? Do you mean you want to save data to database after user performs some action via the application?

Comment: @Kiran Hegde The parsed data needs to be saved in database after user performs some action/validation via the application.That some action can be user accepting data upon reviewing data sets in a Pop Up view with XML format display

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you can perform the following.
In the Appln_parse_xml3 function, currently you are saving all the parsed objects to the database using dbContext.First_DBMLs.InsertAllOnSubmit(groups);
Here instead of saving this, you can bind the objects to a repeater control. This repeater shall show all the parsed objects, with accept button for each object.
You can display the the properties of each object in the repeater item, for the user to be able to judge whether to accept or not to accept. If you want to display the xml for the user, then you can serialize the objects to xml and display them in the repeater.

Once the user clicks accept, then you can create the group object from the repeater item and save it to the database. If you are displaying the object as xml then, you can de serialize the xml to object and save it to the database.

To serialize the object to xml you can use the following function.

```
        private string Serialize(object value)
        {
            System.IFormatProvider provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            string serializedString = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
                XmlWriter xmlTextWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(builder);
                xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, value);
                serializedString = builder.ToString();
                xmlTextWriter.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                serializedString = "Serialization exception  : " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
            }
            return serializedString;
        }
```

You can convert the xml back to your object using the following code

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(First_DBML));
First_DBML ei = (First_DBML)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));
```

I hope I understood properly.

Comment: Which part do you need reference? Binding repeater? Serialize and deserialize?

Comment: To make it more clearer i would like to have references for both Binding repeater? Serialize and deserialize?

Comment: For ther repeater binding you can refer this link. http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/repeater-csharp/.
For the serialize and de serialize, i have updated the answer